# usage of † and ⁜ in wiktionary when translating Chinese

Tags: punctuation

[image]

I have come across with two symbols (that is † and ⁜ in wiktionary) but I don’t know what they mean.
Here is the link: [https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/子](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%AD%90)
Note:
someone has commented that if I can access the computer web browser I can get the usage of them. Unfortunately, I don’t have a computer so I updated the topic and deleted the previous one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about the symbol usage of a specific site, but not about the Chinese language.

Comment: See https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Template:zh-no-solo/documentation. The two symbols seem to mean the same for Chinese on Wiktionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the meaning on the site that is intended for the destop computer:

> †: Obsolete sense in Modern Standard Chinese—may be preserved in fossilised compounds and expressions or other varieties of Chinese.
>
> ⁜: Obsolete sense as a 'stand-alone character' in modern standard Chinese. May be preserved in compounds and idiomatic expressions.

Comment: What does obsolete refer to?